# Store SQL query result into Redis using Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, redis

I am using SQLAlchemy+SQLSoup to query a table, now I need to store the query result as a List in Redis. Any help on how-to would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) then do:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> for e in yourlist:
...     r.rpush('yourlist', e)
```

If you have a complex structure (like an object or a tuple/list) I think your best bet is to serialize the data into some format you prefer (like json or, in case of python, [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)) and simply store it as a string:

```
>>> r.set('key', val)
```

Note that in Redis you can't query data by value, only by key. Details depend on your data, so if you need more precise answer please ask more precise question. :) A sample code would really be best.

Comment: Thanks @Michal, I understand the question was too vague, anyways let me be more clear, I need to store the query fieldname and its associated column values as a grouped list which is ordered. I will be frank, when working with Redis, I am novice. And to add up part of the   query has a field which contains BLOB for file objects. Can you let me know if this can be implemented with Redis ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Michal ,it does solve my problem. Yes we would be serializing the data and save them in Redis. Thanks again.